# Data doesn't display when working with multiple forms

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.NET and have been struggling all afternoon with something. I've found similar questions on the forum but none of them seemed to describe my problem exactly. I'm fairly sure that I'm  missing something very basic.

I have made a main form which currently holds only one button which purpose is to open up a second form and close the main form. Based on the settings the user will select on the 2nd form the first form might have to be adapted to match with the new settings. But the problem occurs even before that.

The 'settings' form has 15 textboxes which I drew onto the form in development mode. They are called ID1, ID2,..,ID15. The values which I want to display in there are saved in an array:

```
Dim ids(15) as integer
```

Next, I created a module to simulate what you could call a control array as I used to use them in VB6.

```
Public sources() As TextBox = [frmSettings.ID1, frmSettings.ID2, //and so on
```

I did this to be able to iterate through all the 15 textboxes:

```
For i = 0 To 14
   Sources(i).Text = ids(i + 1)
Next
```

Then I added on the main form this code to the Button1_Click() event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    frmSettings.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

I did the same thing for the 'exit ' button on the f`rmSettings` form.
This seems to work, but only once. I launch the application, push the button and f`rmSettings` pops up and shows all the values from the array in the textboxes. When I push the 'close' button, I return to the main page.

So far so good, but if I try to return to `frmSettings` a second time, all the textboxes remain blank as if the code I added to the form never gets executed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is the code on the settings form being executed?  Is it in the form's load event?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the array that holds your data is accessible to both forms:

```
Module Module1

    Public ids(15) As Integer

End Module
```

There should **not** be a declaration for "ids" in either form.

Next, make frmSettings itself responsible for loading and saving the data:

```
Public Class frmSettings

    Private Sub frmSettings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim matches() As Control
        For i As Integer = 0 To 14
            matches = Me.Controls.Find("ID" & (i + 1), True)
            If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
                Dim TB As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
                TB.Text = ids(i)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim valid As Boolean = True
        Dim matches() As Control
        For i As Integer = 0 To 14
            matches = Me.Controls.Find("ID" & (i + 1), True)
            If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
                Dim TB As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
                Dim value As Integer
                If Integer.TryParse(TB.Text, value) Then
                    ids(i) = value
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show(TB.Name & ": " & TB.Text, "Invalid Value", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                    valid = False
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If valid Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```